# How to split the same LazyFrame without .clone()?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I have a quite big `.arrow` file (150Gb) I need to split into various parts based on some filters. I started using the Python Polars implementation for prototyping (JIT compiler really helped here) and now I was trying to port my working Python implementation into Rust to hopefully speed up the process in production.
My code looks like this (obviously my code has more complex filters, but I simplified the problem here):

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;
use polars_io::ipc::IpcReader;

fn main() -> PolarsResult<()> {
    // opening .arrow file and parse it as LazyFrame
    let file = std::fs::File::open("./myData.arrow").expect("file not found");
    let df = IpcReader::new(file).finish()?.lazy();

    // Split LazyFrame into various parts
    let df1 = df.filter( col("Volume").gt_eq(0).and( col("Volume").lt(1000) ) );
    let df2 = df.filter( col("Volume").gt_eq(1000).and( col("Volume").lt(2000) ) );
    // ... much more filters
    // let df300 = df.filter( col("Volume").gt_eq(n).and( col("Volume").lt(n+1) ) );

    // printing LazyFrames here to simplify the issue, in the real world I would create new .arrow files based on each filters
    println!("{}", df1.collect()?);
    println!("{}", df2.collect()?);
    // ...
    // println!("{}", df300.collect()?);
    Ok(())
}
```

Obviously, this code won't compile because the borrow-checker wants me to `.clone()` my `df` LazyFrame. So here is the working code AFTER `.clone()`:

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;
use polars_io::ipc::IpcReader;

fn main() -> PolarsResult<()> {
    // opening .arrow file and parse it as LazyFrame
    let file = std::fs::File::open("./myData.arrow").expect("file not found");
    let df = IpcReader::new(file).finish()?.lazy();

    // Split LazyFrame into various parts
    let df1 = df.clone().filter( col("Volume").gt_eq(0).and( col("Volume").lt(1000) ) );
    let df2 = df.clone().filter( col("Volume").gt_eq(1000).and( col("Volume").lt(2000) ) );
    // ... much more filters
    // let df300 = df.clone().filter( col("Volume").gt_eq(n).and( col("Volume").lt(n+1) ) );

    // printing LazyFrames here to simplify the issue, in the real world I would create new .arrow files based on each filters
    println!("{}", df1.collect()?);
    println!("{}", df2.collect()?);
    // ...
    // println!("{}", df300.collect()?);
    Ok(())
}
```

Now the compiler does not complain so I can build it using:

```bash
cargo build --release
```

The problem is that I see at least a 60x performance hit comparing to the same implementation in Python. So it got me confused a bit. I understand the multiple `.clone()` are the cause of slower performance, however my initial understanding was that Polars would optimize such `.clone()` in the context of a `LazyFrame` and avoid unnecessary copies of data, or am I wrong?

Candidly I tried to just filter the reference of `df` using `&df` but the borrow-checker complained too.
I somehow managed to use reference instead of copy using a `DataFrame` instead of a `LazyFrame` but then I somehow lose a lot of methods I use to have in Python (like `with_columns` is not available for `DataFrame` in Rust, or filters need `masks` instead of expressions etc...).

Am I missing some obvious thing? What would be the correct way to RE-use my original `df` LazyFrame instead of `.clone()`-ing it all over and preferably without using `DataFrames` directly :) ?

Comment: By using `IpcReader::new(file).finish()?.lazy()` you're reading the complete file and creating a `LazyFrame` afterwards. Is it more performant to use `LazyFrame::scan_ipc(file)` which only reads the relevant parts of the file?

Comment: Tried `scan_ipc(file)`, it actually gives worst time performance (around 2x slower than `IpcReader::new(file)`. But thanks for the answer!

Comment: Cloning a LazyFrame is very inexpensive and the way to go. I'm still puzzled how you're holding a 150 Gb .arrow file in RAM. Another problem might, if you're writing to disk without a file buffer. Could you provide a full example, in python and rust, where the rust version is slower?

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what you mean about holding 150Gb into RAM, in my laptop it won't fit for sure ahah but in my server it has plenty of room to fit actually. Also, so far I am not even adding the file output to my question, so writing to disk is out of the scope for this question: only the df.clone() operations by themselves are too slow. I can definitely put together the Python Vs Rust code but I have no clue where to upload the data for that, but I'll come up with something.

Comment: I've been mistaken beforehand. Cloning a `LazyFrame` also clones all the data, which is quite expensive in your case. I havent found a function that applies the plan that is constructed by the `LazyFrame` to the data in `DataFrame`.
You could try to simulate this loading the Arrow file into RAM, create a LazyFrame using `LazyFrame::scan_ipc`, apply all your data manipulation and write the LazyFrame to an array file with `.sink_ipc(...)`.

Comment: @raui100 From what I can see, a `LazyFrame` holds an `Arc<DataFrame>` to the underlying DataFrame (via the LogicalPlan) so cloning it should *not* be copying all the data. Also, examining the python bindings, it is liberally cloning `LazyFrame` - which leads me to believe if there is a performance difference between python and rust for this use case, it is not related to the cloning.

Comment: @harmic, you're right! I had just looked at the function signature of `LazyFrame` taking ownership of the `DataFrame` and hadn't investigated any further...

Comment: @JonaRodrigues have you tried the `[nightly, performant, cse]` features of polars? However I'd be pretty surprised if this would result in 60x performance gains...

Comment: I'd insist on raui100's point about the buffer, that could very well explain the x60 performancy hit. Try adding `let file = BufReader::new(file);` between `file` and `df`.

Comment: Unfortunately `let file = BufReader::new(file);` had no impact whatsoever... Thanks anyways. Will try to post a test case tomorrow with reduced file size and both Python & Rust code.

Comment: `[nightly, performant, cse]` polars features  had no impact either.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to optimise your code one way is using smart pointers  :
Instead of using `.clone()` you can use `Rc::clone` as it doesn't make deep copy like `.clone()` (refer: [Rc, the Reference Counted Smart Pointer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-04-rc.html))

Second way is using `unsafe` rust which is not suggested for secure applications (checkout [unsafe keyword docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-01-unsafe-rust.html))

Answer (score 0):

The problem is like by design [the `.filter`](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/main/crates/polars-lazy/src/frame/mod.rs#L76) method on `LazyFrame` consumes the instance (see the self parameter).

Then internally the `opt_state` is a copy and a new logical plan is build and used for a new instance of `LazyFrame`.

So there is a bit of overhead yes. However, when we look deeper into the [`LogicalPlan`](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/main/crates/polars-plan/src/logical_plan/mod.rs#L143) we see that parts of the logical plan are wrapped in `Arc`. E.g. `LogicalPlan::AnonymousScan::function`.

That means that not every bit, that is part of the logical plan is actually copied by issuing the `.clone()` call.

But if you noticed a performance drop, you might want to try to work with the `DataFrame` instead of the `LazyFrame`. Because it's API does not consume it's instance, it [uses self by reference](https://docs.rs/polars/0.32.1/polars/frame/struct.DataFrame.html#method.filter)

```rust
    // do not call `.lazy()`
    let df = IpcReader::new(file).finish()?;

    // Split LazyFrame into various parts
    let df1 = df.filter( col("Volume").gt_eq(0).and( col("Volume").lt(1000) ) );
    let df2 = df.filter( col("Volume").gt_eq(1000).and( col("Volume").lt(2000) ) );
```

In theory, this code should still behave very similarly to the one that clones the `LazyFrame`, but it seems there is a bit less overhead.